# Column name as variable in typeorm querybuilder

Tags: typeorm

This is my original code which does not work.

```
this.createQueryBuilder().where(
      'LOWER(:column) LIKE LOWER(:name)',
      { column: 'itemName', name: `%${options.name}%` }
    );
```

```
{ "total": 0, "results": [] }
```

I get no results from the above query but when I explicitly place the column name in the query like this, it works:

```
this.createQueryBuilder().where(
      'LOWER(itemName) LIKE LOWER(:name)',
      { name: `%${options.name}%` }
    );
```

```
{"total":9, "results": [<RESULTS GOES HERE>] }
```

Is it possible to use a variable in the column name for typeorm?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Yes, but with some drawbacks.

Build your query as a string and parse inside the Where function

```
const query = `{ "${field}": ${value} }`
this.createQueryBuilder.where( JSON.parse(query) )
```

If you want to do more complex, you should write as normal, but in string format.

Comment: See Erics answer above. This risks a SQL injection if implemented this way.

Comment: What i did was to use string concatenation for the column name. But before that I validated the field variable if it is one of the valid strings I accept. for the value I used :name.

Answer (score 3):

I was attempting something similar and stumbled a (not particularly well written) explanation here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typeorm/typeorm_query_builder.htm

Basically, parameters are intended to prevent SQL injection, so while it's hard to see what's going on under the hood, I'm guessing that any string parameter automatically gets wrapped in single quotes in the final query so it can't be interpreted as anything other than a value.

I even tried surrounding the parameter in single quotes, e.g.

```
this.createQueryBuilder.where(
    '":columnName" = :value',
    { columnName: 'my_column': value: 'my_value' }
);
```

No good. This prevents parameter substitution entirely and gives the error `QueryFailedError: column "$1" does not exist` and seems to confirm that this feature is designed to prevent SQL injection.

This does leave template strings or string concatenation if you want to dynamically set column names, table names, etc. However, for the very same reason this safeguard exists in the first place, I would avoid doing that with user input.